# Delay on Loading Data on a Widget

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-widget

my intention is to fetch network data from AsyncTask to android widget.

problem scenario: I add the widget to home screen without opening app(never opened before,only installed) data is about (1 min) delay to load on widget.

Attention: further opening app before load the widget to home screen not occurs mention issue.

I added my codes below.

```
  //AppwidgetProvider class

public class SimpleWidgetDataDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private URL url;
    private RemoteViews remoteViews;
    private String packageName;
    private AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    private int widgetId;


    public SimpleWidgetDataDownloader(RemoteViews remoteViews, String packageName,
                                      AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int widgetId) {
        this.remoteViews = remoteViews;
        this.packageName = packageName;
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        this.widgetId = widgetId;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
        RemoteViews remoteViewsTest = new RemoteViews(packageName,
                R.layout.widget_main);
        remoteViewsTest.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, data);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViewsTest);


        Log.d("WidgetDataDownloader:", "ONPOSTEXECUTE");
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            url = new URL("https://data-sa9.mubasher.net/mix2/ClientServiceProvider?SID=sid&UID=123&RT=26&AI=506941&UE=TDWL&L=EN&UNC=0&M=1&H=1");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("MYAPP", "exception URL", e);
        }
        Log.d("WidgetDataDownloader:", "DOINBACKGROUND");
        //  String titleHeads = webRead(url);

        return webRead(url);
    }


    public static String webRead(URL url) {
        String tag = "webhandler";

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(tag, "error");
        }
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(tag, "error");
        }
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));


        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;


        while (true) {
            try {
                if (!((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)) break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }


}


//simpleWidgetProvider

public class SimpleWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {



    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Log.d("WidgetProvider:","ONUPDATE");
        System.out.println("printed details(WIDGET):" +"");

        final int count = appWidgetIds.length;


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
           /* String number = String.format("%03d", (new Random().nextInt(900) + 100));*/

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_main);
         //  remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView,"TESTERRR" );

           Log.d("WidgetProvider:","tester");
            new SimpleWidgetDataDownloader(remoteViews, context.getPackageName(), appWidgetManager, widgetId).execute();


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }


}

enter code here
```